# Not Getting post data in ajax insert in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am Sending Data to my Codeigniter controller using ajax form external JS file.

This is my ajax Code.

```
$.ajax({                    
                url: 'http://localhost/test/testController/testFunction/',  
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                data: {'name': nameVariable, 'id':idVariable},
                datatype: 'json',                   
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert('Error occured');
                    console.log(e);
                }

            });
```

I get the Success Alert. But in Controller i am not getting the proper value.
this is the my controller code.

```
$data =$this->input->post();
log_message('debug','Ajax Data: '. Print_r($data));
```

What i am doing Wrong here? 
Thanks.

Comment: Check your developer console to see if there are any errors and see what it posting to the server.

Comment: Sir i get "1" in my log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you Should Try Print log like this.

```
log_message('debug','Ajax Data: '. Print_r($data, TRUE));
echo "Data Received Successfully";
```

Because I don't see any error in your ajax code.

To Use Base URL in the External File You can Simply Declare it In your View Page at Just Before this Ajax js file. Assign a variable to it and call it in the external file. 
Like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseURL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
// Now Call this baseURL in the External Js File.  (in ajax Url Like this - url: baseURL,)
</script>
```

Comment: I get the value in log file. Wait.

Comment: can you tell me how do i use base_url in this ajax url.  @AnkitSuthar

Comment: I have Added the Answer. Please Look That First. Thx